# Newline before auto-shrunken UIButton text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

## Background

I am creating an application, and inside of its storyboard I have a `UIButton` element. I need the text of this `UIButton` to auto-shrink, since it scales based on the size of the view. In storyboard, it has the following properties:

[image: properties 1]
[image: properties 2]

Inside of my code, it says:

```
guard button.titleLabel != nil else {
    throw AutoshrinkError.noTitleLabel(button: button)
}

button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
button.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.alignBaselines
```

I know that the `guard` statement passes (i.e. the code below it gets run).

## The Problem

The problem is that with the above setup, my button ends up looking like this:

[image: cut off button]

With a newline before the text.

I have tried editing my code in many ways, including setting `button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines` to `1`, setting `button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakMode.byClipping`, or removing the line about `button.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment`. None of these changes have helped the situation. Instead they wind up causing *more* problems, such as the text not shrinking at all.

If anybody knows how to prevent this newline-scenario from happening, I would appreciate an answer.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit 1

The constraints of the `UIButton` are: 
[image: constraints]

`woodgrain` is a `UIImageView` that is used as a background image.

Comment: what are the constraints you're using for this button? And do you see same error when you're using another font and setting the Button's type to `custom`, instead of `system`?

Comment: @noir_eagle I edited the question in order to add the constraints (See "Edit 1"). As for the `UIButtonType`, I tried both `.custom` and `.system` and the exact same thing happened.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, therefore I need more info. Where do you set the cornerRadius for the button? And what about the font, have you tried to use another font? The problem is clearly not the new line in front of the label, it's somehow misplacing the titleLabel, or stretching the hieght. Have you tried not to use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! All I had to do was add this one simple line:

```
button.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.alignCenters
```

I got the idea to adjust the [`baselineAdjustment`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620524-baselineadjustment) from [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThC96.png) by @rintaro.

Now my `UIButton` looks like this:

[image: new UIButton]